# Shortcut keys for un/comment block of code doesn't work in xcode 8 (suddenly)

Tags: xcode, shortcut

something weird just happen and can't solve it, the command "Command + /" which I used to un/comment block of codes doesn't work any more. when I hit the command the cursers just disappear for a second and than comeback but doesn't comment or uncomment block of code. I changed the shortcut keys to be something else and tried it but it does the same action which is not commenting or uncommenting the code, what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

ok, after install the latest ios update the problem just solved by itself.

Comment: It's a well-known bug. Quitting and restarting sometimes fixes it, or just choosing Editor > Comment by hand instead of using the keyboard shortcut.